# Using for and case loops to sortand move between google sheets and Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

below is some script I have tride to piece together as best I can at this point.  But I am legally blind and need to get some automation done (Hence this script), and when I put into google script editor, it keeps throwing errors "missing ; before line..." but I have checked, and double checked, and from what I can see all ";" that should be in it are ;(!
.

As a VBA coder, I COULD do most of this via that, but  have opted for Google for Sheets and forms, so need to get a grasp on this darn JavaScript stuff now.

Can someone please take some time to look over this, and outline where the errors are?

Much of this code has come from bits and pieces here on stack overflow to see if I can nut it out and learn myself, but I really need some help on this one right now (in a way that will let me learn at the same time).

The concept of this script is eventually to take form submissions and sort them into other sheets on the Spreadsheet based on "courseChoices" and then further on via "Locations"

```
function change(e) { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

``     var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

```
  var sourceRows = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
 var numSourceRows = sourceRows.getNumRows();
 var sourceRowValues = sourceRows.getValues();

 var rowsTransferred = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i <= numSourceRows - 1; i++) {
  var thisSourceRowValue = sourceValues[i];
  // See if the course is a multiple choice of courses
  // in this case column 8  (array 7)
  if (thisSourceRowValue[7].indexOf(",") < 0) {
   // Is  not Multiple choice
   Var CourseChoices = thisSourceRowValue[7]  
  }
  else{
   var courseChoices = thisSourceRowValue[7].split(","); 
   for(var x = 0; x <= thisSourceRowValue[7].indexOf(","); x++) 
    switch(courseChoices(x)) {
     case courseChoices(x).indexOf("Dual") > -1;
     case courseChoices(x).indexOf("Childhood") > -1;
      var Target = "Dual Diploma";
      var courseName = "Dual Diploma in Early Childhood Education and Care";
     break;
     case courseChoices(x).indexOf("Sector") > -1;
      var Target = "Adv Sector";
       var courseName = "Advanced Diploma in Community Sector Management";
     break;
     case courseChoices(x).indexOf("Adv") > -1;
      var Target = "Adv Management";
      var courseName = "Advanced Diploma in Leadership and Management";
     break;
     case courseChoices(x).indexOf("Business") > -1;
      var Target = "CertIII Business";
       var courseName = "Certificcate III in Business";
     break;
     case Default;
      var Target = "Other";
      var courseName = courseChoices(x);
    }
    // checked all multiple choices
   }
   // Made sure we have ALL Choices now
  }
  // See if the sheet exists do more stuff
  if (!ss.getSheetByName(Target)) { 
   // Tab does not exist, so create it
   ss.insertSheet(Target);
   // Ensured Target Tab Exists
   // Insert first row as headers   
   // sort order of columns ....
   var range_input = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:N1");
   var range_output = Target.getRange("A1");
   //sort columns into new orders
   var keep_columns = [0,1,2,3,4,5,10,9,8,11,6,7, 12];
   //Now copy the columns into the target in the new order
   copyColumnNumbers(range_input, range_output, keep_columns);
   }
  //  set our target sheet and target range
  var colNumber = sourceSheet.getLastColumn()-1;
   var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(Target);
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1,     colNumber);
  //  get our source range/row
   var sourceRange = SourceSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
  var targetRows = targetSheet.getDataRange();
  var numTargetRows = targetRows.getNumRows();
  var targetValues = targetRows.getValues();
  for (var y = 0; y <= numTargetRows - 1; y++) {
   var thisTargetRow = targetValues[y];
   // See if the first name, last name and Email are the same
   if (thisTargetRow[2] == thisSourceRow[2] && thisTargetRow[3] ==             thisSourceRow[3] && thisTargetRow[5] == thisSourceRow[5]) {
    // Record Exists, so just alter the coursename 
    thisTargetRow[7] == courseName;
    break;
   }Else if (targetRow[0] == ""){
    // WE have come to a blank line in the target sheet
    // Alter Course to proper Name
    thisTargetRow[7] == courseName;
    // Add new record in correct column orders
   var range_input = thisTargetRow;
   var range_output = thisTargetRow
   //sort columns into new orders
   var keep_columns = [0,1,2,3,4,5,10,9,8,11,6,7, 12];
   //Now copy the columns into the target in the new order
   copyColumnNumbers(range_input, range_output, keep_columns);
    break;
   }
   // records checked in target
  }
  // We have checked all the records now in the Source Sheet
 }
 // ALL DONE!
 }
```

I do have a habit of commenting extensively in my coding, so hope that does not put you off.  Because I cannot see the start and finish of a line alwyys (And therefore  star and end of blocks of code) I use comments to state what I am dong, and wher

---

please email me some fixes if ossible, and WHERE my mmistakes are (As emails will be MUCH easier for me to have read aloud by my voice programs.

Thanks IN advance all ;)

Comment: Here is the link to the actual Spreadsheeet in question

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UAHOPz09-zgFy6AYOwAVWu_CmWGWoRQWaUgx3wyDRyw/edit#gid=205336786